# Detect end loading of iframe inside `UIWebView`

Tags: iphone, cordova, iframe, uiwebview, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a Phonegap project. I have requirement to get content of webpage which opens inside a `UIWebView`.

It is possible using below code.

```
NSMutableString *html = [[[sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Now my question is that I have iframe inside the html page. I could not get iframe's content inside "webViewDidFinishLoad" method.

How to get content inside iframe.

Please give me sunshine.

Comment: Could you provide all code for this method this is running in? I think I know what it is, but what is `sender`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample code :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)sender 
{
NSMutableString *html = [[[sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"] mutableCopy]  autorelease];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  return YES;   
}

- (void)loadAddress:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSString* urlString = self.addressField.text;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. i need to add this string to

```
NSString jsString = @"$('iframe').ready(function() {
              var document1 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('input');
             }";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```